# Illustrator - How to select and rotate multiple artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do you select multiple artboards in Illustrator while in the editor mode and rotate them together with the artwork itself?

Thanks!

Comment: This question may be relevant [Rotate illustrator canvas and contents?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/rotate-illustrator-canvas-and-contents)

Comment: Be aware, you can not rotate any artboard other than for it to be portrait or landscape. In other words, you can't rotate artboards to non 90° angles.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to select multiple artboards, for manipulation. It is also not possible to rotate artboards. Artboards can only be in horizontal or vertical configuration.

But a alternate workflow, if only somewhat inferior to actually being able to do this, could be:

1. Draw rectangle geometry for each the artboard.
2. Select everything you need.
3. Move and rotate as you wish, keeping in mind that artboards have to be aligned in monitor position.
4. Remake the artboards with boxes as guides.
5. delete boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, contrary to opinion, I have just rotated some text using the rotate tool, only to have all of  the art boards on a 15% angle. I have reset the workspace, and no change! If I could remember exactly what I did, I could both help with the question and fix my own problem.

Comment: Please dont use answer fields for comments or questions. Things have a tendency to change in 6 years. Yes the newest new verion can in fact rotate the entire view.