# Is there a way to rotate an artboard along with the contents?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, rotate

I created an envelope in Illustrator and when I finished I switched the orientation from landscape to portrait. While the artboard does switch, the artwork remains landscape and I have to switch that by hand using the rotation tool.

Is there a way to switch the orientation of an artboard that includes the contents in the switch?

I've searched for an answer but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do automatically, you can use the Rotate tool and then rotate (or with the Selection tool).

**[Related post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/28442/63979)**

---

You can also use this nice [script](https://github.com/mprewitt/AI-Rotate-Artboard/blob/master/RotateArtboard-90R.js) by *Michael Prewitt* on Github which does it for you (it rotates everything 90°)

```
// Rotate Artboard 90 degrees clockwise

// INSTALLATION:
// Install in /Applicatons/[Illustrator folder]/Presets/en_US/Scripts

// DESCRIPTION:
// Rotate the artboard in 90 degree increments.

// SOURCES:
// https://forums.adobe.com/message/9074536#9074536

// Make sure we have an open document, or else open one
if( app.documents.length == 0 ) {
    fileToProcess = File.openDialog();
    app.open(fileToProcess);
}

var doc = app.activeDocument;

var currentArtboard = doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex();
var currentArtboardRect = doc.artboards[currentArtboard].artboardRect; // Rect, which is an array;
var currentLeft = currentArtboardRect[0];
var currentTop = currentArtboardRect[1];
var currentRight = currentArtboardRect[2];
var currentBottom = currentArtboardRect[3];
var currentWidth = Math.abs( currentRight - currentLeft );
var currentHeight = Math.abs( currentBottom - currentTop );

var centerX = currentLeft + (currentWidth/2);
var centerY = currentTop - (currentHeight/2); // Y axis is inverted

var newArtboardRect = [];
var newWidth = currentHeight;
var newHeight = currentWidth;

// Rotate the artboard 90 degrees

newArtboardRect[0] = centerX-(newWidth/2);
newArtboardRect[1] = centerY+(newHeight/2); // Y axis is inverted
newArtboardRect[2] = centerX+(newWidth/2);
newArtboardRect[3] = centerY-(newHeight/2); // Y axis is inverted

doc.artboards[currentArtboard].artboardRect = newArtboardRect;

// Set ruler origin to center, rotate everything around custom pivot, reset the ruler

var currentOrigin = [ newArtboardRect[0], newArtboardRect[1] ]; 

// currentArtboard.rulerOrigin = currentOrigin;
doc.rulerOrigin = currentOrigin;

// currentArtboard.rulerOrigin = [newWidth/2,newHeight/2];
doc.rulerOrigin = [newWidth/2,newHeight/2];

// alert("Rotation X Y coords are " + newWidth/2 + ", " + newHeight/2 + ".");



// CURRENT BUG:
// Setting the rulerOrigin does NOT work



var pItems = doc.pageItems;  
for(var i = 0;i < pItems.length;i++){
    pItems[i].rotate(270,true,true,true,true,Transformation.DOCUMENTORIGIN); 
}

doc.rulerOrigin = currentOrigin;
```

> <sup>Note: The current release is extremely buggy. It works (sometimes!) for very simple graphics. However, there are two significant bugs: (1) It will sometimes scatter objects during the rotation of the artboard; this happens quite often with more complex artwork, and occasionally with artwork that seems simple. (2) It will sometimes rotate the artboard 180 degrees instead of 90.</sup>

[image]